# How can I create an instance of form in async methods in c#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I want to create an instance of `frm_client` and my `on_MessageRecived`
method is an `async`. There is a problem about creating an instance and I couldn't find out. When I debug the code and create an instance of `frm_client` it is not working.

```
private void on_MessageRecived(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    int data_size= f_clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);
    string data = makeString(buffer, data_size);
    bool k = messageParse(data,f_userName);

    if (k)
    {
        ClearArray();
        f_clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(on_MessageRecived), null);
    }
}

private bool messageParse(string message, string text)
{
    switch (message.Substring(0, 3))
    {
        case "~g~":
            if (bool.Parse(message.Substring(3)))
            {
                frm = new frm_client();
                frm.LoginForm = this.LoginForm;
                frm.Show();
                this.LoginForm.Hide();
                return false;
            }
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Which problem? Do you get some error?

Comment: No , I dont. it is like working in a loop.http://i68.tinypic.com/2d0f3gy.png